# unwanted symbol appearing in integrated terminal in vs code

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, zsh, babun

I'm using an embedded terminal in VS code for windows, but using zsh provided by babun as the shell.

I've also configured the prompt in the windows terminal app a little bit.

For some reason, the terminal app shows the prompt how I expect it to look: 
[terminal on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkpeF.png)

but the integrated terminal shows me a '%' symbol above each line:
[integrated terminal in vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77XAt.png)

I'm still fairly new to customizing shells and have not been able to find a solution looking online, or playing around with the theme file myself.

I was hoping someone could look at my theme file below and help me understand what the possible offender for the '%' symbol could by could be:
[modified babun.zsh-theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp738.png)

I modified lines 4 and 10, to show the whole path in line 4 and show no path in line 10. The originals are commented out.